# How to stop and disable the "this device can now be safely removed from the computer" message

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to stop and disable (or even remove) the "this device can now be safely removed from the computer" message?

This is because I have to click the `OK` button everytime and I am testing about 200 thumb drive (USB Flash drive) and it has become quite annoying.

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running? For me, on Windows 7 Home Premium x64, if I left-click the *"Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media"* taskbar icon then choose the device to eject, I just get a "tooltip" message that says "Safe to Remove Hardware"... nothing for me to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot seems to be from Vista or perhaps Win7. As Kevin mentioned in his comment above, you shouldn't even see a modal dialog if you left-click the Safely Remove tray icon once and eject the drive from the device list (only a balloon tooltip should be displayed).

Optimising drives for Quick Removal is a possibility, but not really feasible when there are ~200 drives involved. If you want an easier and quicker way to eject USB drives, use Uwe Sieber's [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools-e.html) or one of the alternatives mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/486647/138343).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the device in "quick removal" mode (it is likely already set, see [this old answer of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/410454/is-time-a-substitute-for-safely-remove-hardware/410462#410462) for instructions on how to check it and change the mode) you can just remove the usb stick without having to do the safely remove hardware every time beforehand.

Comment: May I know if it also mean that I will need to set `quick removal` for each USB Flash drive that I plug in (since they are of different size, vendor, etc). Are there any software for Windows that can perform this removal without any message. (Error message such as `locked` application is OK to appear but if it is successfully, I just wish to see the USB disk icon disappear from the `Computer` window.)